# How can I determine how much memory a process is using in AIX?

Tags: memory, process, aix, nix

How can I determine how much memory a process is using in AIX?

Answer (score 5):

`svmon` is the most comprehensive tool for doing this on AIX.

`svmon -P <pid>`

will get you the full and glorious output.  Obviously `man svmon` helps with interpreting that (just remember, by default, nearly all of the numbers are page counts, which are usually 4KB in size).

You can also get a very nice summary with memory shown in MB using,

`svmon -P -O summary=basic,unit=MB`

Comment: +1 for "just remember, by default, nearly all of the numbers are page counts, which are usually 4KB in size"

Comment: include the options filtertype=working,segment=off and you will see the real memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can see memory usage with:

```
ps v PID
```

where PID is the process ID you are checking.

You can find info about the variables displayed here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/mem_usage_determine_ps.htm

You will be more interested in **SIZE** (Virtual size in paging space in kilobytes of the data section of the process) and **RSS** (Real-memory size in kilobytes of the process)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [topas](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/topas.htm)? It's pretty good for that sort of thing.

You can also try [nmon](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-analyze_aix/) but it's third party, so you'll have to download and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ps -p PID -o command,size
```

where PID is the process ID that you're interested in?

Comment: Do I type literally "command,size"?

Comment: Yes, those are the field names for the output option: `-o`

Comment: This doesnt work for me, I get the error: 

ps: 0509-048 Flag -o was used with invalid list.

Comment: @AndrewBrennan: try `ps -p PID -o comm,rss`